# How to write .htaccess if django project is in subfolder and subdomain?

Tags: django, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

The path to my django site is: `staging.ninjawebsite.com/clients/project/`.

I want that to be treated as the base url. The django project is in the `public_html/clients/project` subfolder. Everything seems to be working fine but all links to say `/city/` should go to staging. `ninjawebsite.com/clients/project/city/` but it goes to `staging.ninjawebsite.com/city/`.

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
  AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi 
  Options +FollowSymLinks 
  RewriteEngine On 
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteRule ^(media/.*)$ - [L]
  RewriteRule ^(admin_media/.*)$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}!(django.fcgi) 
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /clients/project/django.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Somebody please help me! Thanks.

Comment: Why is your code in a publicly accessible path on the webserver?

Comment: I dont understand. What do you mean?

Comment: Sound like you need to define one or more [name based virtual hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html#using) in your httpd.conf, with an suitable DocumentRoot, and restart apache.